# Pandas: In pivot_table, how to custom fill missing values?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill the missing values in my Pandas pivot_table with values from the index and to fill the missing Year Week columns.

```
import pandas as pd

d = { 'Year': [2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019],
        'Week': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'Part': ['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
        'Static': [20,20,20,40,40,40],
        'Value': [np.nan,10,50,np.nan,30,np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Part','Static'], columns=['Year', 'Week'], values=['Value'])

print(pivot)

            Value
Year         2019
Week            2     3     5
Part Static
A    20      10.0  50.0   NaN
B    40       NaN   NaN  30.0
```

In the example above, the Weeks 1, 4 & 6 are missing because they don't have values. As for the `NaN`, I want to fill them with a value from the "left", so for Week 1 for Part A the value will be 20.0, and for Week 4 to 6 will be 50.0, and the same for Part B where all `NaN` will be filled with values from the left.

The expected output is

```
            Value
Year         2019
Week           1     2     3     4     5     6
Part Static
A    20     20.0  10.0  50.0  50.0  50.0  50.0
B    40     40.0  40.0  40.0  40.0  30.0  30.0
```

PS: I can refer to a reference calendar dataframe to pull in all the Year Week values.

Edit:

I tested the solution on my data, but it seems to not work. Here is an updated data with Week 4 being removed.

```
d = { 'Year': [2019,2019,2019,2019,2019],
        'Week': [1,2,3,5,6],
        'Part': ['A','A','A','B','B'],
        'Static': [20,20,20,40,40],
        'Value': [np.nan,10,50,30,np.nan]
   }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#Year Week data set for reference
d2 = {'Year':[2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019],
        'Week':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] }
```

Answer (score 2):

fill the column `Value`, first filling down the column, and then filling across the with the `Static` value

```
df.Value = df.groupby('Part')[['Static', 'Value']].ffill().ffill(axis=1).Value
```

After this operation, the `Value` column has an `object` type. So it is necessary to cast as `int`.

```
df.Value = df.Value.astype('int')
```

Then, pivot as usual, but also `ffill` & `bfill` after on the horizontal axis

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Part','Static'], columns=['Year', 'Week'], values=['Value']).ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)

# outputs:

            Value
Year         2019
Week            1     2     3     4     5     6
Part Static
A    20      20.0  10.0  50.0  50.0  50.0  50.0
B    40      40.0  40.0  40.0  40.0  30.0  30.0
```

Comment: Hey Haleemur, I am getting a `No numeric types to aggregate` error on the pivot? What might be going wrong here?

Comment: @Shantanu, quite possibly after the first operation `df.Value` ends up as a text, so you would then need to cast it to int. see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Unfortunately, the test data that I had did not exactly match the one in the database. I have updated the data. Can you let me know how to get  the same output? I have a Year-Week reference dataset as well.

Answer (score 2):

`unstack` `reset_index` and `fillna` is one option:

```
df.set_index(['Year','Week', 'Part', 'Static']).unstack([0,1]).reset_index().fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)

     Part Static Value                    
Year              2019                    
Week                 1   2   3   4   5   6
0       A     20    20  10  50  50  50  50
1       B     40    40  40  40  40  30  30
```

`fillna` with `methond='ffill'` will forward fill data so when you set `axis=1` it forward fills left to right.